# Remember authentication in Firebase Unity Games

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the new official firebase unity (beta) package for online data in my Game. Whenever I kill the app in iOS, I have to enter my login credentials again. I do not want to save email and password in the PlayerPrefs as this seems completely insecure. Is there (already) a way to persist the login state, so that a user only has to sign in once after downloading the app and never again after that?

Thanks for any help,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to persist a user session if the app is terminated. You can create  Firebase user tokens for this purpose. You can however not create these tokens through the Unity SDK. You will need to run the Admin SDK (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), generate them with that and send them to the client. The TokenAsync function in the SDK only generates an ID token. Not an access token.

I implemented a solution based on this a few days ago only to find out that the custom tokens generated by the Admin SDK have an expiration time limited to 3600seconds(1hour). Which is quite short and ultimately it didn't really help me auto-login users if they had suffered from a crash or just terminated the app.

You can instead use Facebook/Google tokens that persist for a bit longer. The Facebook Unity-sdk is quite easy to use and you can get an access token straight from it which you can use to authenticate via the Firebase Unity-sdk. I have not tried a Google login solution yet so I cant comment on that.

**EDIT:**
Please dont store email/password locally. That is not the way to go.